# ColdFusion Round function

Tags: math, coldfusion, rounding

Today I come across unexpected behavior or lack of knowledge with ColdFusion 9,10,11 Round function here is my scenario

Round(28.5) ---> result is 29 expected
**Round(0.285*100) ---> result is 28 not expected**

Round(precisionEvaluate(0.285*100)) ---> result is 29 using precisionEvaluate!
Round(Evaluate(0.285*100)) ---> result is 29 using Evaluate!
This is not big decimal, why I would need to use precisionEvaluate or Evaluate on a number?
On farther research I found more interesting behavior
**Round(0.285*100) result is 28 --WHY? I'm expecting 29-- !**

Round(0.295*100) result is 30 ---- Correct !
Round(0.275*100) result is 28 ---- Correct  !
Round(0.185*100) result is 19 ---- Correct  !
Round(0.385*100) result is 39 ---- Correct  !

#### What is is big deal with 0.285*100?

Comment: The precisionEvaluate() working to "fix" the issue is a clue that the problem is implicit float issues. CF converts your decimal from a non-type specific variable to a float and back again causing imprecision associated with that operation. It's the downside of a typless language.

Comment: @MarkAKruger thanks for your prompt response, I totally understand the issue of non-type variables. Why it is not happening with Round(0.385*100) & Round(0.185*100) only with Round(0.285*100)!

Comment: I'm not sure and it makes me scratch my head as well - but under the hood the lack of precision probably tracks with the size of the number - the smaller the number the more likely. That's my guess and I wouldn't be suprised if I was totally wrong (ha). But I'm pretty confident that precision is still the issue.

Comment: What about rounding 0.1425 * 1000 ?  It is exactly half 0.285, so it should have the same mantissa in floating point representation. -- Ah, I tried on cflive.net and it works properly. 0.145*100 however, is also broken.

Comment: It's not really anything to do with CFML being loosely typed, @MarkAKruger. It's just how binary needs to deal with fractions, and how arithmetic of same will amplify the errors. It's more an issue with CFML hiding this than it being an actual unexpected issue.

Comment: I suppose you are right. However, wouldn't it be different if you specify type and precision in advance?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's not the precision of the decimal numbers, it's how the underlying floats are stored in Java. This demonstrates:

```
<cfoutput>
<cfloop array="#[0.275,0.285,0.295]#" index="s">
#s.getClass().getName()#
<cfset f1 = s + 0>
#f1.getClass().getName()#
#f1.toString()#
<cfset f2 = f1*100>
#f2.toString()#
#round(f2)#<br>
</cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

Output:

> java.lang.String java.lang.Double 0.275 27.500000000000004 28
>
> java.lang.String java.lang.Double 0.285 28.499999999999996 28
>
> java.lang.String java.lang.Double 0.295 29.5 30

I can only assume under the hood CF uses better precision when converting from a string to a float when performing `<cfset f1 = s + 0>` as there's no dodgy rounding there. However having performed the multiplication step we're getting an accuracy error bleeding in. 28.5 ends up being just shy of 28.5, so rounds to 28 not 29. It's just a binary fraction arithmetic issue.

BTW, there's nothing special about 0.285. A lot of numbers are similarly effected (have a look at the range from 0.005 to 5.05). You just happened to pick a bunch that aren't (other than 0.285).

Comment: @Adam, I appreciate the time and effort to explain this. If it is binary fraction arithmetic issue don't you believe this should be fixed? the only workaround I did is by using precisionEvaluate. My client is financial institution every penny count. The way I found this issue by balance report which I'm comparing values between different back-end. I will test this using .Net

Comment: It's not a CF issue, it's just "how stuff works". The `27.500000000000004` values are the *Java* results of those operations; CF is just reporting back what Java tells it. The issue is more that CF hides it, so makes it a "surprise" when things seem to go "wrong". Floating point arithmetic is inherently inaccurate, and binary fractions are even more so. Put 'em together and... well: you see what you get.

Comment: (Edit) *Floating point arithmetic is inherently inaccurate* .. which is why [approximate numeric types like `Double` are unsuitable for currency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) . If you need that kind of precision, you must stick with a more precise type like `BigDecimal`, which as you discovered, is what `PrecisionEvaulate()` gives you. Just be careful not to mix the result of PrecisionEvaulate() with any other operators ie `+-/*` or CF will implicitly convert it back to a Double again.