# ColdFusion floor Function After Division

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

Having a bit of an issue with the behaviour of ColdFusions floor. I would expect flooring the value 3316 would result in 3316. However, it is resulting in 3315 which is odd. Can anyone explain this behaviour?

```
<cfset myvalue = 33.16/>
<cfset myrate = 1/>
<cfset ratedec = myrate/100>
<cfoutput>No Floor: #myvalue/ratedec#<br/></cfoutput>
<cfoutput>With Floor: #floor(myvalue/ratedec)#</cfoutput>
```

Output:
No Floor: 3316
With Floor: 3315

Expectation: No Floor: 3316  With Floor: 3316

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27494253/coldfusion-round-function/27494971 TLDR: coldfusion is hiding the fact that the result is actually something like `3315.9999999999995`, so when you floor it it of course rounds down as it should.

Comment: The cause is a duplicate, but unless you know the floating point behavior of this math, it may not be easily discoverable. You can `javacast("bigdecimal",x)` to cast the values to a non-floating type, and it will make the issue more visible. But this may need to be approached differently.

Comment: Yep thanks - using precisionevaluate for the multiplication worked.